# Jquery: Check whether next element contains a particular text

Tags: jquery

This is my sample table structure,

```
<tr height=20>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Brand A</td>
    <td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr height=20>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Brand B</td>
    <td>2000</td>
</tr>
<tr height=20>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Brand C</td>
    <td>3000</td>
</tr>
<tr height=20>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Brand D</td>
    <td>4000</td>
</tr>
```

If i use

```
const name = $("td:contains('Apple')").first();
console.log(name.next().next().text());
```

I am getting the log as 1000, But i need to get the element which has next **td** tag as "**Brand C**" and to log the next value **3000**

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
const name = $("td:contains('Apple')").last();
```

When you search for the `td:contains...` it will retrieve all DOM elements that match that selector, and you have three, so it retrieves them in order of appearance (read from top to bottom, left to right). So `first` gives you the one in the first row, not the third row, as you might like.

Comment: there may be many <tr> tags after that! this wont work for my case

Comment: If you're going to have that amount of `<tr>` tags then searching the DOM tree with jQuery will be extremely inefficient and a huge performance hit

Answer (score 0):

As with all jQuery collections you can also use their index or work backwards from the end using negative index

Can also use `filter()` on them such as to find one with sibling with specific value

```js
let $cells = $("td:contains('Apple')");
console.log('Found ', $cells.length, ' matches');

// change firt one background
$cells.eq(0).css('background','lightgrey');

// get number from row of second one
console.log('Second # =', $cells.eq(1).siblings().last().text())

// target second last
$cells.eq(-2).css('background','yellow');

// use filter
$cells.filter(function(){
   return $(this).next().is(":contains('Brand C')")
}).css('background', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr height=20>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Brand A</td>
    <td>1000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height=20>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Brand B</td>
    <td>2000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height=20>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Brand C</td>
    <td>3000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
const apple = $("td:contains('Apple')");
$(apple).each(function(){
 if($(this).next().text() === "Brand C") {
  console.log($(this).next().next().text());
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr height=20>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Brand A</td>
    <td>1000</td>
</tr>
<tr height=20>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Brand B</td>
    <td>2000</td>
</tr>
<tr height=20>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Brand C</td>
    <td>3000</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is fine for finite number of tr tags, but i will have many tr tags